Format float in N chars max with best precision
For concise display in chart titles, I would like to format arbitrary floating point values as a fixed size string, in Python. Either decimal (0.0123) or in scientific notation (1.2e-2) but with the highest precision possible (choosing decimal here). The result is allowed to be smaller than the fixed size, so for instance trailing decimal zeros can be stripped off.
I searched high and low for a solution, algorithm or library, as I'm sure I'm not the first to have this need. But I did not find anything useful. And it's harder than it sounds.
I guess the interface can be:
def format_short(nr: float, maxwidth: int = 4) -> str:
    # ...
    return "1.23"

Of course values exist where no representation can possibly fit at all when maxwidth is small enough (6 or less), but those are rare in practice and a simple placeholder label can be chosen (like 'inf').
Depending on maxwidth, values like 9.95E-1 and 9.95E9 are where things get really hairy...
Isn't there a standard solution to this common problem?

Consider the amount of “waste” (characters that are not significant digits). There are four in “1.2e−2”, the period and the “e−2”. There is one in “1.2345”, the period. The latter format is value dependent; “1.2345” has one, “0.1234” has two, “0.0123” has three, and so on. This suggests that, to maximize precision, you should use the exponential format only when it has less waste, i.e., when the latter format would start with the five characters “0.000”. (If the exponential format ever gains another digit, as in “1e-10”, it remains less wasteful than the fixed format.)…

… So, for the criterion based on precision, you merely need to test whether the number is less than .001, with some care about how rounding is handled at that point. This threshold does not depend on maxwidth; which format is less wasteful depends on the leading zeros of the fixed format, not the width available. (You also need to use the exponential format if the number is too large for the fixed-precision format, but that is a separate issue.)

The threshold does depend on maxwidth, exactly because of the "care about how rounding is handled"...

Show a case where the choice differs based on maxwidth.

I already did. Try 9.95E9.

9.95E9 is not a counterexample. As my comments said, if the value is too large for fixed-point format in a particular width, you use the exponential format. If it is less than .001, you use the exponential-format. Otherwise, you use the fixed-point format. This works for 9.95E9: For widths 9 and less, the former condition applies: 9.95E9 cannot fit into the fixed-point format, so you use the exponential format. For greater widths, 9.95E9 is not less than .001, so you use the fixed-point format…

…  If you still think you have a case where the choice for a particular value depends on the width other than as I have stated, then show the value, a width for which the preferred choice is the exponential format, the string resulting for that, a width for which the preferred choice is the fixed-point format, and the string resulting for that.

You are right for choosing between fixed-point or exponential format. But with how many decimals? That to me is the harder question.
